# How do you use downloaded templates in Django

Tags: python, css, django, templates

I have found these really cool templates online and I would like to use them for building my website. Is there any way of not copying the links for bootstrapping but for me to use the templates downloaded and tweak them?

I have looked online and all they suggested was bootstrapping.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want to do. What exactly is the difference between copying the links, and downloading these? It might make things simpler if you given an example.

Comment: Say for example I found good templates available for download from this website: https://colorlib.com/wp/template/riddle/ and then I click download. I get a whole file of all the templates given. Normally in tutorials, they go to websites like materializecss.com and copy link hrefs for the base. Instead of doing what the tutorials do, I would like to use the premade templates and put them on the website that I would like to create.

Answer (score 1):

When using html templates, you will probably find that each html file has the same header and footer information.  You will need to pull this header/footer information out into a base template (typically `base.html`).  Each page type (html files other than base.html) that has had the header/footer information removed will then extend the `base.html` template file:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/overview/#design-your-templates

If the template has quite a few pages, it will likely take you a while to get everything broken out as it needs to be, especially when you're new.

Comment: It did not work. If you just see the comment that I made against Willem Van Onsem, I think you will get a better picture of what I am talking about.

Comment: Only the stuff that was in the base template showed up. The rest did not.

Comment: I think you're expecting the creation of a new Django website from a template to be automatic like it can be in WordPress with a template that is specifically set up for WP.  Using a custom template to create a Django site won't be a matter of clicking a few buttons.  I downloaded the template that you provided a link to in your answer to Wm. Van Onsem.  It is structured as expected - header/footer information is repeated in each html file.  If you follow my answer, you'll get what you need as far as setting up a new Django site, but it will take time (hours, if not days).  Good luck!

Comment: You have to create a block in the base template into which the content specific to each page will be placed.  Look online for examples of {% block content %} {% endblock %}.